# Set tag attribute based on variable value with kendo binding

Tags: kendo-ui, validation

1. I create a variable list of input elements which are bound to a kendo MVVM.
2. I have a kendo validation running over all my input elements (this is standard functionality), checking if the input is empty.
3. The objects in my MVVM have an attribute IsMandatory, like this:

   `{ Name: "test", ID: 12, ... , IsMandatory: false }`
4. The validation must not try to validate elements with an IsMandatory value of false. How can I achieve this?

I know I can bind attributes to MVVM values like this:

```
<input data-bind="attr: { name: Name }" />
```

Which results in an actual output like this for the object above:

```
<input name="test" />
```

However, the `required` attribute used for the standard required validation is value-less, like this.

```
<input name="test" required />
```

So basically I need to create elements with a required attribute if the IsMandatory attribute in my MVVM object is set to true, and without the required attribute if it is set to false.

```
{ Name: "test1", ID: 1, ... , IsMandatory: true }
{ Name: "test2", ID: 2, ... , IsMandatory: false }
{ Name: "test3", ID: 3, ... , IsMandatory: true }

<input name="test1" required />
<input name="test2" />
<input name="test3" required />
```

Is there an elegant solution to this problem? Other than putting an if-else around the creation of each element. Or is there a different solution of excluding/including elements in my validation?

One option I could imagine would be to create a custom required validation, checking if the IsMandatory attribute for the input is set to true and only then validate the element. However, I could not find any possibility to get my hands on the MVVM object of the current element.

```
...
validation: {
    required: function (input) {
        var observable = // Get the kendo observable from input here !!!!!
        if (observable.IsMandatory) {
            return input.val() != "";
        }
        return true;
    }
},
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be implemented as a [custom binding](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/mvvm/bindings/custom):

```
kendo.data.binders.required = kendo.data.Binder.extend({
  refresh: function() {
    var required = this.bindings.required.get();
    if (required) {
      this.element.setAttribute("required", "required");
    } else {
      this.element.removeAttribute("required");
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/atozib/1/edit

Comment: This sets the required attribute as required="required".
However, reading about attributes without value I've realized it does not matter if you set a value and furthermore what the value looks like. So, your answer does solve my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have realized this only works with certain inputs. When I try to apply this binding to a kendo combo box I get the message:
`The required binding is not supported by the ComboBox widget`

Comment: Yeah this binder will work only for HTML elements and not for widgets. You can make it work for widgets too - check the documentation link that I've put in my answer.

Comment: So in order to make this work for both, regular HTML input elements as well as kendo widgets I understand I have to create two binders, each of a different name, while the name itself doesn't matter, I can name it whatsoever.

I've been on that documentation site but must have read that part over. Thank you so much.