# Bind the addition of required attribute on an element

Tags: jquery, mvvm, kendo-ui

Is it possible to Bind the visibility of the HTML5 required attribute on an element using Kendo UI MVVM?

The required attribute being on an element indicates that a value for that element is required. Technically the attribute should have a value of 'required' as well.

With Kendo UI I am able to bind a value to the attribute with

```
<input data-bind="attr: { required: isFieldRequired }"/>
```

However, this still outputs the required attribute in the rendered HTML, which is not what I want (again, because it being present indicates requiredness).

I can listen for the change event on the dataSource, and manually add or remove the attribute using jQuery and using values on the ViewModel, however this isn't ideal.

If there is a way to bind whether an attribute is rendered, that would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Atanas Korchev's answer(link below) you just need to add custom binding then it worked pretty well for me.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/15947852/2692411

First add the custom binding

```
kendo.data.binders.required = kendo.data.Binder.extend({
  refresh: function() {
    var required = this.bindings.required.get();
    if (required) {
      this.element.setAttribute("required", "required");
    } else {
      this.element.removeAttribute("required");
    }
  }
});
```

Then on your input just use the required attribute

> `<input data-bind="required: isRequired"/>`

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need to use

```
data-bind="attr: {data-required-msg:insuranceEmailRequiredMsg,validationMessage:insuranceValidationMessage}"
```

And js: in viewmodel observable define these two attributes:

```
insuranceRequiredMsg:"Msg is required"
insuranceValidationMessage:"Msg is invalid"
```

Comment: Nope - the addition of a data-required-msg doesn't set the required attribute. I'm also not convinced that you can actually bind to the data- attributes that way.

Comment: I have just ended up using the viewmodel to pass a list of required fields in. While it's not great, it does just mean that I can set all the fields required at load time, which is all I really need. Then when loaded, just use jQuery to set the required attribute if it finds the control specified.

Comment: I am not clear with your question. You want to set value to required attribute? Can u explain it clearly?